# Expansion Port & Final Cartridge et al - Are they just programs in ROM, or is there more to it?

Tags: commodore-64

For the C64, there are a lot of emulation devices floating on (Euro) ebay that allow you to load programs from SDcard via emulated serial floppy or/and tape interfaces, simulating the insertion of a disk by selecting a e.g. ".d64" file from SDcard.

While I have seen clones of particular modules for the expansion slot, e.g. Final Cartridge III, I have never seen a generic module in the vein of above mentioned drive emulators where you can load some module file from SDcard.

Why is that? Would it be possible to do? Is all such a module is just 6510 opcodes in ROM that get loaded into RAM on boot, nothing else?

I do remember that such modules had "cheat" functions like pausing a game and storing / retrieving its state to/from disk etc - I'm not sure whether this required some extra logic in the module and use of special signal lines from the expansion port.
That would mean that VICE module files must contain more than just opcode, and stuff that only works in VICE.

OTOH if I'm just confused about the above and it's as straightforward as it seems to otherwise look , I'd like to give making such a module myself a try.

---

**EDIT**:
Ok, I can't precisely answer my own question, but this find gives me some idea that it's indeed more complicated... This module supportes a few very specific modules, and has a Xilinx FPGA on it from the looks of it, so apparently they figured not even a fast MCU would do it...

[EasyFlash3](http://skoe.de/easyflash/ef3intro/)

Comment: They were much more. As far I know, many of them contained actually yet another 6502 CPU and they were a complete SoC.

Comment: Seems you're right, see the EDIT on my post.